# react-native display image in GLView

Tags: reactjs, webgl, native, expo

I'm trying to display an image on a GLView in react native.
I was inspired by this link to write my code https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-drawimage.html

I have this component who calls a GLContext2D class:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Expo from 'expo';

import GLContext2D from '../../lib/GLContext2D';

export default class Scene extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      ready: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    (async () => {
      this._textureAsset = Expo.Asset.fromModule(
        require('../../test.jpg')
      );
      await this._textureAsset.downloadAsync();
      console.log("ok");
      this.setState({ ready: true });
    })();
  }

  render () {
    return this.state.ready
      ? <Expo.GLView
          style={styles.view}
          onContextCreate={this._onContextCreate}
        />
      : <Expo.AppLoading />;
  }

  _onContextCreate = gl => {
    console.log(this._textureAsset);
    var ctx = new GLContext2D(gl);
    var test = ctx.createTextureFromAsset(this._textureAsset);
    ctx.clear();
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    ctx.drawImage(test.texture, test.width, test.height, 0, 200);
          gl.flush();
        gl.endFrameEXP();
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    width: 500,
    height: 1000,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow'
  }
});
```

And the GLContext2D class:

```js
import Expo from 'expo';
import {mat4} from 'gl-matrix';

const vertSrc = `
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;
uniform mat4 u_textureMatrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
  v_texcoord = (u_textureMatrix * vec4(a_texcoord, 0, 1)).xy;
}
`;

const fragSrc = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  if (v_texcoord.x < 0.0 ||
      v_texcoord.y < 0.0 ||
      v_texcoord.x > 1.0 ||
      v_texcoord.y > 1.0) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1); // blue
    return;
  }
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
`;

export default class GLContext2D {
  constructor(gl) {
    var vert;
    var frag;

    this._gl = gl;
    vert = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vert, vertSrc);
    gl.compileShader(vert);
    frag = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(frag, fragSrc);
    gl.compileShader(frag);

    this._program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(this._program, vert);
    gl.attachShader(this._program, frag);
    gl.linkProgram(this._program);

    this._locations = {
      position: gl.getAttribLocation(this._program, "a_position"),
      texcoord: gl.getAttribLocation(this._program, "a_texcoord"),
      matrix: gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "u_matrix"),
      textureMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "u_textureMatrix"),
      texture: gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "u_texture")
    };
    this._createBuffers();
  }

  _createBuffers() {
    var positions;
    var texcoords;
    var gl;

    gl = this._gl;
    this._positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._positionBuffer);
    positions = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this._texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._texcoordBuffer);
    texcoords = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(texcoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  }

  async createTextureFromAsset(asset) {
    var gl;
    var tex;
    var texData;
    var img;

    gl = this._gl;
    tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));

    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

    texData = {
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
      texture: tex,
    };

    texData.width = asset.width;
    texData.height = asset.height;

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texData.texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, asset);

    return (texData);
  }

  //ctx.drawImage(tex, texWidth, texHeight, dstX, dstY);
  //ctx.drawImage(tex, texWidth, texHeight, dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight)
  drawImage(
        tex, texWidth, texHeight,
        srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,
        dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight, srcRotation) {
    var gl;
    var matrix, matrix2;
    var texMatrix;

    if (dstX === undefined) {
      dstX = srcX;
      srcX = 0;
    }
    if (dstY === undefined) {
      dstY = srcY;
      srcY = 0;
    }
    if (srcWidth === undefined) {
      srcWidth = texWidth;
    }
    if (srcHeight === undefined) {
      srcHeight = texHeight;
    }
    if (dstWidth === undefined) {
      dstWidth = srcWidth;
      srcWidth = texWidth;
    }
    if (dstHeight === undefined) {
      dstHeight = srcHeight;
      srcHeight = texHeight;
    }
    if (srcRotation === undefined) {
      srcRotation = 0;
    }

    gl = this._gl;
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.useProgram(this._program);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._positionBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this._locations.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._locations.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._texcoordBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this._locations.texcoord);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._locations.texcoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    matrix = mat4.create();
    matrix2 = mat4.create();
    mat4.ortho(matrix, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, -1, 1);
    mat4.translate(matrix2, matrix, [dstX, dstY, 0]);
    mat4.copy(matrix, matrix2);
    mat4.scale(matrix2, matrix, [dstWidth, dstHeight, 1]);
    mat4.copy(matrix, matrix2);
    gl.drawingBufferHeight = 320;
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this._locations.matrix, false, matrix);
    texMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.fromScaling(texMatrix, [1 / texWidth, 1 / texHeight, 1]);
    mat4.translate(matrix2, texMatrix, [texWidth * 0.5, texHeight * 0.5, 0]);
    mat4.copy(texMatrix, matrix2);
    mat4.rotateZ(matrix2, texMatrix, srcRotation);
    mat4.copy(texMatrix, matrix2);
    mat4.translate(matrix2, texMatrix, [texWidth * -0.5, texHeight * -0.5, 0]);
    mat4.translate(texMatrix, matrix2, [srcX, srcY, 0]);
    mat4.scale(matrix2, texMatrix, [srcWidth, srcHeight, 1]);
    mat4.copy(texMatrix, matrix2);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this._locations.textureMatrix, false, texMatrix);
    gl.uniform1i(this._locations.texture, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  }

  clear() {
    var gl;

    gl = this._gl;
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  }
}
```

I have a blue screen with the clear function but nothing appears from drawImage function.

Comment: here is a simpler code snippet to draw an image in react-native-webgl (which is forking Expo GLView but eventually will get merged back):

https://github.com/react-community/react-native-webgl/blob/master/example/App.js

Answer (score 0):

First off, please learn how to make a [*Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Emphasis on **minimal**.

Looking at your code in `drawImage` you have the size of the canvas hard coded

```
mat4.ortho(matrix, 0, 1000, 1000, 0, -1, 1);
```

It seems like you'd want

```
mat4.ortho(matrix, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, -1, 1);
```

Also I have no idea what this line is for

```
gl.drawingBufferHeight = 320;
```

Finally I notice you have `createTextureFromAsset` as an async function but you'd not calling it with an `await`

```js
const vertSrc = `
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;
uniform mat4 u_textureMatrix;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_matrix * a_position;
  v_texcoord = (u_textureMatrix * vec4(a_texcoord, 0, 1)).xy;
}
`;

const fragSrc = `
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
  if (v_texcoord.x < 0.0 ||
      v_texcoord.y < 0.0 ||
      v_texcoord.x > 1.0 ||
      v_texcoord.y > 1.0) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 1, 1); // blue
    return;
  }
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
`;

class GLContext2D {
  constructor(gl) {
    var vert;
    var frag;

    this._gl = gl;
    vert = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vert, vertSrc);
    gl.compileShader(vert);
    frag = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(frag, fragSrc);
    gl.compileShader(frag);

    this._program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(this._program, vert);
    gl.attachShader(this._program, frag);
    gl.linkProgram(this._program);

    this._locations = {
      position: gl.getAttribLocation(this._program, "a_position"),
      texcoord: gl.getAttribLocation(this._program, "a_texcoord"),
      matrix: gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "u_matrix"),
      textureMatrix: gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "u_textureMatrix"),
      texture: gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "u_texture")
    };
    this._createBuffers();
  }

  _createBuffers() {
    var positions;
    var texcoords;
    var gl;

    gl = this._gl;
    this._positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._positionBuffer);
    positions = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    this._texcoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._texcoordBuffer);
    texcoords = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(texcoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  }

  async createTextureFromAsset(asset) {
    var gl;
    var tex;
    var texData;
    var img;

    gl = this._gl;
    tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        new Uint8Array([0, 0, 255, 255]));

    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

    texData = {
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
      texture: tex,
    };

    texData.width = asset.width;
    texData.height = asset.height;

    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texData.texture);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, asset);

    return (texData);
  }

  //ctx.drawImage(tex, texWidth, texHeight, dstX, dstY);
  //ctx.drawImage(tex, texWidth, texHeight, dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight)
  drawImage(
        tex, texWidth, texHeight,
        srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight,
        dstX, dstY, dstWidth, dstHeight, srcRotation) {
    var gl;
    var matrix, matrix2;
    var texMatrix;

    if (dstX === undefined) {
      dstX = srcX;
      srcX = 0;
    }
    if (dstY === undefined) {
      dstY = srcY;
      srcY = 0;
    }
    if (srcWidth === undefined) {
      srcWidth = texWidth;
    }
    if (srcHeight === undefined) {
      srcHeight = texHeight;
    }
    if (dstWidth === undefined) {
      dstWidth = srcWidth;
      srcWidth = texWidth;
    }
    if (dstHeight === undefined) {
      dstHeight = srcHeight;
      srcHeight = texHeight;
    }
    if (srcRotation === undefined) {
      srcRotation = 0;
    }

    gl = this._gl;
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.useProgram(this._program);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._positionBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this._locations.position);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._locations.position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._texcoordBuffer);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this._locations.texcoord);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._locations.texcoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    matrix = mat4.create();
    matrix2 = mat4.create();
    mat4.ortho(matrix, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height, 0, -1, 1);
    mat4.translate(matrix2, matrix, [dstX, dstY, 0]);
    mat4.copy(matrix, matrix2);
    mat4.scale(matrix2, matrix, [dstWidth, dstHeight, 1]);
    mat4.copy(matrix, matrix2);
//    gl.drawingBufferHeight = 320;
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this._locations.matrix, false, matrix);
    texMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.fromScaling(texMatrix, [1 / texWidth, 1 / texHeight, 1]);
    mat4.translate(matrix2, texMatrix, [texWidth * 0.5, texHeight * 0.5, 0]);
    mat4.copy(texMatrix, matrix2);
    mat4.rotateZ(matrix2, texMatrix, srcRotation);
    mat4.copy(texMatrix, matrix2);
    mat4.translate(matrix2, texMatrix, [texWidth * -0.5, texHeight * -0.5, 0]);
    mat4.translate(texMatrix, matrix2, [srcX, srcY, 0]);
    mat4.scale(matrix2, texMatrix, [srcWidth, srcHeight, 1]);
    mat4.copy(texMatrix, matrix2);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(this._locations.textureMatrix, false, texMatrix);
    gl.uniform1i(this._locations.texture, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
  }

  clear() {
    var gl;

    gl = this._gl;
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  }
}

function loadImageP(url) {
  return new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "";
    img.onload = fulfill;
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = url;
  });
}


const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const gl2D = new GLContext2D(gl);

async function load(url) {
  const e = await loadImageP(url);
  const tex = await gl2D.createTextureFromAsset(e.target);
  gl2D.drawImage(
     tex.texture, tex.width, tex.height,
     0, 0, 300, 150);
};
      
(async function() {
  await load("http://i.imgur.com/iFom4eT.png");
}());
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.3.2/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: The problem with react-native or the GLView from Expo, is that _gl_ does not contain a _canvas_ object, so _gl.canvas_ is equal to undefined and produces an error.

I used the following line because when I printed the _gl_ object, _drawingBufferHeight_ was equal to zero, so I've tried to set it manually:
`gl.drawingBufferHeight = 320;`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have any idea for an equivalent of _gl.canvas_ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you want to set the size of a canvas use `gl.canvas.width = desiredSize` but better to [use CSS and then adjust the canvas to match](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-resizing-the-canvas.html). This would seem especially true for React but you're using React Native which I have no experience with